# Will the edge case posts trigger Revival badge?

Tags: discussion, bug, badges

After pushing **Go get it** button on the **Revival badge** tooltip, which has the following description:

> **How do you earn this badge?**
>
> Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer
>   scoring 2 or more

it redirected me to the search page with following search parameters:

`is:question score:1 answers:0 intags:mine closed:no created:..2016-06-01`

Then I selected the newest option from the list, it says it was asked **29 days ago**:

[image]

Is it a bug or do I miss something?

**Update**

Wouldn't it be better to use created:..2016-05-30 instead? In that case more than 30 days ago will be always true interdependent of time.

I am wondering if **Revival badge** will still work for **29 days ago** cases?

Comment: Bug related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327309/click-on-the-go-get-it-button-in-badge-description-displays-an-error-page

Answer (score 1):

One of the search query parameters is

```
created:..2016-06-01
```

which is correct, because it's 30 days from today (July 1st). However, this question was asked a few minutes before midnight, so that is only 29.5 days ago, which is rounded down to 29.

[image]

So we're always in a situation here where, depending on what time you run it, the query either returns (at most) almost one day worth of questions too much, or too few.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `created:..2016-05-30` instead? In that case **more than 30 days ago** will be always true interdependent of time. I am wondering if `Revival Badge` will still work for these cases?

Comment: If `created:..2016-05-30` would be used, the query would miss the questions created on June 1st up to 14:06 CET (the time of posting this comment) which would be at least 30.00001 days old. If that's enough to trigger the query, no idea.

Comment: True, it depends on a query that is used to trigger the badge, if it is still triggering for edge cases, then it is ok, else I would prefer to have fewer results.