# Click on the "Go get it" button in badge description displays an error page

Tags: bug

[image][image]

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

- Navigate to your S/O profile (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/users/4317945/ga-sacchi)
- Click on the *next badge* title in the badges section after choosing **Electorate** as goal badge
- Click on the "Go Get It" button in the popup that appears with the badge description

RESULT:

- A S/O page reporting an internal error is displayed after a few seconds.
  The link displayed is https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=recent&hideReview=on&minScore=0

Comment: You know that you have separate badges for main and meta?

Comment: yep, description amended :)

Comment: Furthermore the website loading a new page once the "Go get it button" is clicked is not the best UX in my opinion. Maybe an alert describing what's going on could improve it? 
PS. I sent a few requests using the faulty button now a maintenance page is displayed (second pic attached)